# How do I include externally-built C/C++ libraries (e.g. OpenSSL) in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I want to develop a C++ Android app using Android Studio.

If I need to include an external library, I may need to build it separately. For example, I may need OpenSSL which has Android NDK build instructions [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android). The instructions in that link are of this kind:

```
sudo -E make install CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include my_prog.c -o my_prog.exe -L /usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

If I'm reading this right, the first line cross-compiles the library and the second line builds `my_prog`, linking to said library. But if I am using Android Studio to build the app, how do I integrate that with the library produced via the `make install` line?

Comment: Note that that page is three years old, and especially "sudo make install" for a cross-compiled library is not the right thing to do.